# How to test a service in Spring Boot that use an Elasticsearch repository?

Tags: elasticsearch, integration-testing

So, I wrote a class service that use a repository (extend from ElasticsearchRepository). All operations  are performed on an elasticsearch instance running on a remote server.
Now, I want to test my service, test (save, delete, search) operations, but I can't test on elasticsearch instance from the server. I must to test on another instance of elasticsearch. How can I do it ?
Thanks!